# firebase cloud functions ssl certificate for ssl pinning?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi i am trying to implement ssl pinning for my ios app. Where do I get my certificate for my firebase cloud functions endpoints? I want SSL pinning to prevent man in the middle attack. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Idk but I need a certificate file for my ios app so I can implement SSL pinning.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a Google certificate using "openssl" command. Several solutions you can find in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website) ServerFault question. Also, I found a pretty similar question in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083773/firebase-cloud-functions-hosting-ssl-pinning/47087409#47087409).